# Allow only one of multiple attributes in an ActiveRecord model to be present at a time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to make it so that only one of three columns can be filled at any given time.

Here's some pseudocode of what I had in mind:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :column_one, presence: true,
    absence: true if (:column_two.present? || :column_three.present?)
  validates :column_two, presence: true,
    absence: true if (:column_one.present? || :column_three.present?)
  validates :column_three, presence: true,
    absence: true if (:column_one.present? || :column_two.present?)
end
```

Is it possible to do this at the model level, or do I have to just manage it in the controller or params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do the check in a single validation without repeated code, use a custom validation method:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :there_can_be_only_one
end

def there_can_be_only_one
  if [column_one, column_two, column_three].count(&:present?) > 1
    column_with_error = column_one.present? ? :column_one : :column_two
    errors.add(column_with_error,
      "can't be present if any other column in [column_one, column_two, column_three] is also present"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a proc with `unless`:

```
validates :column_one, presence: true, unless: Proc.new { |r|
  r.column_two.present? || r.column_two.present?
}
validates :column_two, presence: true, unless: Proc.new { |r|
  r.column_one.present? || r.column_three.present?
}
validates :column_three, presence: true, unless: Proc.new { |r|
  r.column_one.present? || r.column_two.present?
}
```

Or a symbol that names a function:

```
validates :column_one, presence: true, unless: :other_columns_present

private

def other_columns_present
  # do checks here
end
```